# Bulma tiles not defaulting to horizontal

Tags: css, bulma

According to the Bulma docs on tiles (https://bulma.io/documentation/layout/tiles/) I would expect the following to produce two horizontal rows of two images each. Instead, it produces a line of four vertical images, with the first and second and third and fourth somewhat closer to each other.

```html
    <div class="tile is-ancestor">
        <div class="tile is-parent">
            <div class="tile is-child"><img src="{{ site.baseurl }}/res/img/image1.svg"></div>
            <div class="tile is-child"><img src="{{ site.baseurl }}/res/img/image2.svg"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="tile is-parent">
            <div class="tile is-child"><img src="{{ site.baseurl }}/res/img/image3.svg"></div>
            <div class="tile is-child"><img src="{{ site.baseurl }}/res/img/image4.svg"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I was able to get the behavior I wanted by forcing `display: flex` on the `is-parent` div (which is the class I would expect, actually, rather than `display: block`, which is what Bulma sets), but my understanding is that Bulma tiles should lay out horizontally by default. Am I wrong, or doing something wrong?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of doing this is to define two divs with class `is-ancestor`:

```
    <div class="tile is-ancestor">
        <div class="tile is-parent">
            <div class="tile is-child"><img src="{{ site.baseurl }}/res/img/image1.svg"></div>
            <div class="tile is-child"><img src="{{ site.baseurl }}/res/img/image2.svg"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tile is-ancestor">
        <div class="tile is-parent">
            <div class="tile is-child"><img src="{{ site.baseurl }}/res/img/image3.svg"></div>
            <div class="tile is-child"><img src="{{ site.baseurl }}/res/img/image4.svg"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I think you're right that that's how it's intended to be set up; but it still produces two groups of vertically-aligned images for me. At least the workaround works well enough for now!

Comment: That is exactly what this does. Wasn't this what you asked for?

Comment: No; I was looking for two horizontally-aligned rows of two images each; basically a square. This produces a single vertical column of images (or technically two vertically-aligned rows stacked on top of each other).